# How To create Audit table in sql server ? i need to create each audit table or can manage single table all audit

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am using MVC5.  created Entity framework. i have totally 15 tables . now i want Recent activity  in my Project . i have plan use audit  table . i  need to create audit each table or single table can mange ? what are  fields come on inside audit  table ?

I have TP_users table

```
Id  int Unchecked
UserName    nvarchar(50)
UserEmail   nvarchar(50)    
DisplayName nvarchar(50)    
Password    nvarchar(50)    
RoleId      int
IsActive    bit 
ClientId    int
```

Now i want create audit table TP_users table .whare are fields come inside audit table ?  how to use Audit table entity framework ?

Comment: Take a look at [Audit.EntityFramework](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/tree/master/src/Audit.EntityFramework#auditentityframework) library.

Answer (score 1):

We use an entity like below:

```
public class Audit
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(6)]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string Changes { get; set; }
    public string PK { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime RevisionStamp { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

We use this for auditing all of our tables. `Action` property says what type of change has occurred like 'update', 'insert' or 'delete'. Column values before and after the change are saved in `Changes` column as a JSON like below:

`[{"FieldName":"ID","ValueBefore":"2","ValueAfter":"2"},{"FieldName":"SettingTypeIndex","ValueBefore":"FiscalYear","ValueAfter":"FiscalYear"},{"FieldName":"Value","ValueBefore":"2015","ValueAfter":"2016"},{"FieldName":"Year","ValueBefore":"0","ValueAfter":"0"},{"FieldName":"DateInserted","ValueBefore":"2016-04-11 8:45:08 AM","ValueAfter":"2016-04-11 8:45:08 AM"},{"FieldName":"DateModified","ValueBefore":"2016-07-28 9:45:46 AM","ValueAfter":"2016-07-28 9:47:17 AM"},{"FieldName":"CreatorUserID","ValueBefore":"b44792db-1fbd-44d2-9f7d-cf05c6a2f922","ValueAfter":"b44792db-1fbd-44d2-9f7d-cf05c6a2f922"},{"FieldName":"UpdaterUserID","ValueBefore":"b44792db-1fbd-44d2-9f7d-cf05c6a2f922","ValueAfter":"b44792db-1fbd-44d2-9f7d-cf05c6a2f922"}]`

So this way we can have the rollback functionality (if ever needed). The primary key of the changed record is saved in `PK` property. The date of the change is saved in `RevisionStamp` propery and finally the table name and username are saved in `TableName` and `Username` properties respectively. Of course this entity is mapped to a table in database and the data is persisted in that table.

If you are using entityframework you can override `DbContext.SaveChanges()` method and get all the `ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e=>e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)` items and create your audit data using those items.

Comment: i have using stored procedure  . then audit table also create stored procedure ?

Comment: If you are using EF, then you don't need stored procedures to achieve this, Otherwise I think you should use triggers to know when a change is occurred in any table, then use your stored procedure to insert the data in audit table.

Comment: i save the code model folder. where i change DbContext.SaveChanges()?

Comment: If you are using model-first, your dbcontext class should be under your edmx file and then under [yourcontextname].tt file, like the one in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424.aspx;

Answer (score 0):

here you go for some help 
1. https://web.archive.org/web/20210506085627/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041807-1.shtml